# When transiting Beijing (PEK), citizens of which countries need visas?

Tags: air-travel, visas, china, transit, pek

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China#Visa-free_transit_within_any_international_airport) it seems that anyone can make the transit without a visa, but I'm not convinced. Where can I get some more official information on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on international flight, staying less than 24 hours in airport, and are not leaving it, you do not need a transit visa.

Look at [Chinese embassy website](http://www.china-embassy.org/eng/hzqz/zgqz/t84242.htm).

Comment: When you say "not leaving it" you mean the airport? because that's not true.. Last July I flew from Manila to London with 14 hours transit in Beijing and I went to the city with no visa.

Answer (score 2):

Updated information about transit visa in Beijing:

In order to facilitate the international visitors’ short stay for sightseeing in Beijing, the city now adopts a visa-free transit policy, which allows transit passengers with passport of the following 45 countries to stay in Beijing for 72 hours without visa on direct transit from January 1, 2013:

Argentina, Austria, Australia, Belgium, Brazil, Brunei, Bulgaria, Canada, Chile, Cyprus, Czech Republic, Denmark, Estonia, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Hungary, Iceland, Ireland, Italy, Japan, Latvia, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta, Mexico, Netherlands, New Zealand, Poland, Portugal, Qatar, Romania, Russia, Singapore, Slovakia, Slovenia, South Korea, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, United Arab Emirates, Ukraine, United Kingdom, United States.

http://www.travelchinaguide.com/cityguides/beijing/visa-free.htm